# Magento 2.3.2. How do I change the default coupon error message?

Tags: magento2.3.2, coupon-codes

I just need to find where to change the 'This Coupon is not valid' message. I want to make it a bit more informative - "This Coupon is not valid. Please make sure you have registered an account, or that the coupon code is correct". I can find the coupon success message, but not this one.

Any pointers would be gratefully received.
TIA

Comment: Override this controller function and change your desired message
vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/CouponPost.php

Comment: Try with  en_US.csv  "The coupon code ""%1"" is not valid.","The coupon code ""%1"" is not valid."

Comment: vendor/magento/module-checkout/i18n/en_US.csv , update there and execute setup upgrade and deployment command for render changes in static file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento check coupon code in
`vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/CouponPost.php`

```
$this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                            __(
                                'The coupon code "%1" is not valid.',
                                $escaper->escapeHtml($couponCode)
                            )
                        );
```

And Magento translate coupon error message in en_US.csv.

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/i18n/en_US.csv
```

Line num: 20

```
"The coupon code ""%1"" is not valid.","The coupon code ""%1"" is not valid."
```

Comment: Thank you all. I added the new line in the translate csv. That did the trick.